# Unable to locate a config with ConfigParser

Tags: python, linux

I am attempting to open a configuration file, read a value, and then use that value to open another configuration file.  Specifically, my config files are located under $HOME/bin/config, in a file named Profile.ini.  Then, this gives me the info of whether I should be opening another config named Configuration.ini that is located in either $HOME/bin/config/config1, $HOME/bin/config/config2.  The python code itself is being run from $HOME/TestSystems.  However, when I attempt to run this code, it ends up not finding the configuration file and being unable to open it.  Below is my code:

```
import ConfigParser

class ConfigManager(object):
    """docstring for ConfigManager."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConfigManager, self).__init__()
        self.path = '$HOME/bin/config/'

    def getConfig(self):
        path = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        print self.path+'Profile.ini'
        path.read(self.path+'Profile.ini')
        for sectionName in path.sections():
            print 'Section:', sectionName
            print '  Options:', path.options(sectionName)
            for name, value in path.items(sectionName):
                print '  %s = %s' % (name, value)
            print
        activeProfile = path.get('Profiles', 'ActiveProfile')
        configPath = self.path + activeProfile + '/Configuration.ini'
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        configProfile = config.read(configPath)
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
$HOME/bin/config/Profile.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):

activeProfile = path.get('Profiles', 'ActiveProfile')
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Profiles'
```

Which means that this code isn't finding the configuration and opening it properly.  I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with this code and what I need to do to make it work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to use the shell variables in the python.

I took the liberty of slightly adjusting your code according to the standard of PEP8 ( including bug fix ):

```
import ConfigParser
import os


class ConfigManager(object):
    """docstring for ConfigManager."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConfigManager, self).__init__()
        self.path = os.path.join(
            os.environ['HOME'],
            'bin/config'
        )

    def get_config(self):
        parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        print(os.path.join(self.path, 'Profile.ini'))
        parser.read(
            os.path.join(self.path, 'Profile.ini')
        )
        for section_name in parser.sections():
            print('Section:', section_name)
            print('  Options:', parser.options(section_name))
            for name, value in parser.items(section_name):
                print('  %s = %s' % (name, value))
            print()

        config_path = os.path.join(
            self.path,
            parser.get('Profiles', 'ActiveProfile'),
            'Configuration.ini'
        )
        config_profile = parser.read(config_path)
        print(config_profile)
```

Comment: When I run this, the first print message prints "/bin/config/Profile.ini", when the file (on this machine) under "/home/vagrant/bin/config/Profile.ini".  Then it is unable to find the ini file, and of course, fails.

Comment: So, looks like there is no `$HOME` variable in your shell. You can setup it from python code ( `os.environ[HOME] = '/home/vagrant'` ) or provide as default ( replace `os.environ['HOME']` with `os.environ.get('HOME',  '/home/vagrant'` )